# Based on given time, estimate input size the algorithm can process

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

If we know the time complexity of an algorithm/program is `O(E log V)`, and have *tabled data* of its execution times on different input sizes, how would I *estimate* the input size `V` this program can accomplish in example **30** seconds?

```
+------+---------+
|  V   |    T    |
+------+---------+
|   10 | 0,00018 |
|   20 | 0,00046 |
|   30 | 0,00091 |
|   40 | 0,0018  |
|   50 | 0,0020  |
|   60 | 0,0029  |
|   70 | 0,0038  |
|   80 | 0,0035  |
|   90 | 0,0069  |
|  100 | 0,008   |
|  200 | 0,037   |
|  300 | 0,093   |
|  500 | 0,35    |
|  750 | 0,95    |
| 1000 | 1,87    |
| 1500 | 6,26    |
| 2000 | 13,06   |
+------+---------+
```

Comment: Note that E depends on V (if V, E are graph vertex and edge counts)

Comment: It would help to include an example of this table; does it include numbers for V and E, or just V?

Comment: Include it anyway, otherwise anyone who answers will have to make their own one up and hope it is similar enough to yours for the answer to be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Time for [Linear Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_approximation); let's do it with a help of **R** language:

Create a *csv file* with the last (i.e. the most precise) numbers, say:

```
V;T
200;0.016
300;0.047
500;0.13
750;0.42
1000;0.82
1500;2.8
2000;5.8
```

and execute **R** script

```
df <- read.csv("C:\\data.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
df$LogV = log(df$V)
df$LogT = log(df$T)

m <- lm(df$logV ~ df$logT)

summary(m)
```

You'll get

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)     
(Intercept) 6.941998   0.020574  337.42 4.34e-12  
df$LogT     0.390779   0.009129   42.81 1.31e-07 
--- Signif. codes:  0 ‘’ 0.001 ‘’ 0.01 ‘’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.04787 on 5 degrees of freedom 
Multiple R-squared:  0.9973,    
Adjusted R-squared:  0.9967  
F-statistic:  1832 on 1 and 5 DF,  
p-value: 1.313e-07
```

Correlation **R** is pretty good, and the corresponding formula is

```
 LogV = 6.941998 + 0.390779 * LogT
```

Or

```
 V = Math.Exp(6.941998) * Math.Pow(T, 0.390779)
```

Note, that we have `O(T**0.4)` not `O(log(T))` in fact; if you test

```
  mLog <- lm(df$logV ~ df$T)
```

you'll have *much worse* correlation. Let's compare the estimations `(Est. V)` on existing values `T` and compare the estimations with actual `V`:

```
  V  (Est. V)   T
-----------------
  10 (  25) 0.000
  20 (  36) 0.000
  30 (  48) 0.000
  40 (  66) 0.001
  50 (  66) 0.001
  60 (  77) 0.001
  70 (  86) 0.002
  80 (  82) 0.002
  90 ( 105) 0.003
 100 ( 114) 0.004
 200 ( 206) 0.016
 300 ( 313) 0.047
 500 ( 466) 0.130
 750 ( 737) 0.420
1000 ( 958) 0.820
1500 (1547) 2.800
2000 (2057) 5.800
```

If we put `T = 30` we'll get estimation for `V = 3909` or better say `V ~ 4000`

Comment: @Joe: Linear Regression (or `lm` - Linear Model in terms of R) is not an easy task to implement in the simplest case it involves *pseudo inverse matrix* and alike technique, that's why I suggest a library `R` (built in); `ML.net`, `Accord.Net` for C#, `numpy` for Python etc.

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to know how `E` depends on `V`.

If there is no useful info, try to divide the second column values by logarithm of the first column.

Then try to approximate resulting values by some function - seems that quadratic dependence looks reasonable (and number of edges in dence graph is proportional to square of vertex count).

When `E=G(V)` is found, use result formula to get numerically value of `V` to reach 30 seconds. For example (with quadratic function):

```
Time(V) = C*V*V*log(V)
```

Estimate `C` constant and find where function `Time(V)` intersects `T=30` seconds horizontal line.

Comment: I see in Excel that `E=V^2` is good enough approximation, though `E=log(V)*V^2` approximation is slightly better, so final compexity looks like `O(log(V)^2*V^2 )`. The first point lies out - but we can add some "starting time" constant.

Comment: 1) Find constants using some large values 2) Walk V values with some step until time becomes too large. 3) Walk the last step range with smaller steps (repeat until needed tolerance is reached)   Better way - use any simple [root-finding algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) - will work fast, because function is smooth